# PayPal API call to get all recurring payment profile "paying" my account

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

How can I retrieve a list of all recurring payment profiles that are set up against my account? (that is they are putting money into my paypal account).

I'm using the merchant services (https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#merchant)

There is a an API called TransactionSearch but that's not an ideal way to retrieve all the profile ids...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Transaction search would be about the only way to do a search for active profiles.  The better method would be to keep track of this on your side.  You could use [IPN](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro) to send all the data back to your system.  You would get the details when a new profile is created, when payments are processed, and when the profile is cancelled.  You could then query your database for the needed information.